# DataBound Combobox in C# is not working properly

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox

I have one combobox, it's populated with database contents. My problem is once I selected one item every item in the combobox is same.

Example: Combobox items: (Before Selection)

- jhon
- Kunal
- Mark

I selected Mark in the combobox. If I tried to change another item, Every item 
 becomes Mark.

Combobox items: (After selection)

- Mark
- Mark
- Mark

Comment: Maybe some code would help us identify the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "If I tried to change another item" ? Explain your problem in more detail

Comment: @tariq Thanks for your reply. First I selected Mark. Then I want select jhon instead of mark.

Comment: @PaulFrancis I bounded combobox with database by using visual studio not by programatical.

Comment: @SarathJasrin , post all the code of the cs file.

Comment: @tariq      this.personnelTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSetPersonnelC.Personnel);

Comment: @SarathJasrin edit your question and post code their. That will be better to understand. Besides try and post all the code .. copy paste. We need to see if their is something that can cause this... are their any OnClick or OnSelect events associated with the combobox ?

Comment: Dear @tariq, There is no code involved in the process. I bounded the data with combobox by using visual studio wizard. Not by code.

Comment: that I understand, but is there no other code in the file? No events nothing?

Comment: @tariq This new from, no code related to comobox.

Comment: @tariq Finally I tried to bound the data by using programatically.  It's working fine! Thanks for your response.

Comment: @SarathJasrin Good for you :)